# Use default language domain when editing translated content

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have a multi-lingual site setup that uses two domains:

- example.com (Primary/Default English domain)
- example.mx (Spanish translation)

When editing translated content the user is forced to 'example.mx/node/[nid]/edit' which forces the user to login for both 'example.com' and 'example.mx'.

Is there a way to allow translated content to be edited on a path for the primary domain as opposed to the domain setup for that language?